# Enable the second button on submitting first button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my first button...

```
 <div class="control-group col-xs-12">
```

Confirm

This is my script for enabling validation for the registration form.

```
$(".btn-confirm").click(function() {
    validate();
    $('#register_personnummer, #register_name, #register_email, register_verify, register_address ,register_zip , register_district ').change(validate);
});

function validate() {
    if ($('#register_personnummer').val().length > 0 &&
        $('#register_name').val().length > 0 &&
        $('#register_email').val().length > 0 &&
        $('#register_verify').val().length > 0 &&
$('#register_address').val().length > 0 &&
$('#register_zip').val().length > 0 &&
$('#register_district').val().length > 0 &&
$('#register_phone').val().length > 0) &&


{
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
}
else {
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
}



}
```

This is my second button...

```
<div class="submit">
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back" value="my-account" />
    <a class="payson-submit" href="">
</div>
```

This is my second javascript I want to show this button when i enter confirm of first button only after validating all required fields.

```
$(".btn-confirm").click(function(ev) {

    //$('.payson-submit').css('display','block');
    var frm = $('#payment-form');
    frm.submit(function(ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                if (data) {
                    $('.btn-confirm').css('display', 'none');
                    $('.payson-submit').css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                    $('.btn-confirm').css('display', 'block');
                    $('.payson-submit').css('display', 'none');
                }
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Please do help me over this,.... Thank you...

Now this works... I have forget to put the onclick='return register_now()' which makes it redirect rather popping into the first button.
Thank you all of you for your help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You can't select the second `.btn-confirm`?

Comment: I want to show the second button . for the next process.

Comment: Now when i click the first confirm button it will redirecting to another page but i want to stay in that page only with second button to show and first button to be hide automatically.

Comment: You have syntax error in your `validate` function, inside if statement you close parenthesis before `&&` but never open.

Comment: yes i got that... now edited with solutuions ..thank you